# Is it possible to lock a widget

Tags: android, widget

The default longclick event of the widget enables the user to delete it. Is it possible to lock the widget so the user couldn't delete it? I would certainly build in an if condition to the let the user decide when they want to delete the widget.

Comment: My educated guess would be that you can't restrict user from deleting the widget. I can't see why you 3rd party developers should be able to do it.

Comment: I don't know how android works on other phones but in a comment to an app I read "could use a way to lock it to the screen maybe..I've accidentally deleted it a couple times." I cannot accidentally delete it on my phone, but maybe it's the feature of Desire HD :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to lock the widget so the user couldn't delete it?

There is no API for this, sorry.